# What happens if JMS message is sent without JMSPriority header

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

I am currently trying to prioritize messages (JMS) going through a complex application.

In the part that concerns me most, users insert the messages into a table in the DB like table `INPUT` with columns `DESTINATION`,`PRIORITY`, `MESSAGE`. Priority column is not mandatory, both others are mandatory.

The application then takes the information from entries in this table and creates JMS with `JMSPriority = PRIORITY` header. Body is filled with BODY column and the JMS is then sent to queue specified in `DESTINATION`.

CODE SNIPPETS:

```
//pull requests from database and set headers
from(RouteConstants.READ_REQUESTS_FROM_DATABASE) //this is a route formed by SQL 
    .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_JBOSS")
    .process(setHeaderProperties) 
    .to("direct:jms");
```

---

```
//send JMS to destination
from("direct:jms").setBody(simple("${property.MESSAGE}"))
.convertBodyTo(String.class).recipientList(
simple("jms:queue:${property.DESTINATION}?
exchangePattern=InOnly&jmsMessageType=Text&preserveMessageQos=true
&disableReplyTo=true"));
```

---

```
public class SetHeaderProperties implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
      LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap body = (LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap) exchange.getIn().getBody();
      exchange.setProperty("MESSAGE", body.get("MESSAGE").toString());
      exchange.setProperty("DESTINATION", body.get("DESTINATION").toString());
      Long priority = getPriorityQuery(); //DAO method that returns value of PRIORITY or null if empty
      if(priority != null) exchange.setProperty("PRIORITY", priority);
}
```

---

```
//Receive the JMS. Consider this point to be the same that the message was sent to in the second snippet
from("jms:queue:input-msgs").
log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, CAMEL_LOGGER_NAME, "Received JMSPriority: ${header.JMSPriority}").    //This getter is problematic, see below snippets
process(generalMessageProcessor);
```

The application behaves as should as long as `PRIORITY` column is filled. When the value of `PRIORITY` is `null`, the getter always returns `4`. I understand, that the priority `4` is default, and I am OK with the message being processed as such, but I need to be able to differentiate when priority 4 was set as a fixed value in the database table and therefore requested, or if the priority was not set at all and therefore the program should behave in slightly different route inside the following processor.

Is this at all possible? I would like to avoid changing DDL of the database and also I cannot just fork the program in the `SetHeaderProperties` processor, as the information would get rewritten in the `GeneralMessageProcessor` anyway and the setter processor does not have all the necessary classes and fields exposed.

The naive answer I suppose would work is to call the DAO query again whenever I need to check the priority, but that would strain the database and I would like to know if there is more elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the value `4` is the default JMS priority. Therefore, every message has a priority and there is no such thing like a `null` priority or no priority at all.

However, one quite simple workaround that does not strain the database would be to set another message header like `prioritySetByApplication` or whatever name you like. You can then use this header to differ between a default priority and an "explicit" priority of `4`.